# Написание простого бота

Tags: python

Хочу написать бота. Проблема: когда на вопрос "есть ли у тебя друзья" я пишу "есть", бот выдаёт: "Так ты уже взрослый. Уже ходишь в универ/колледж?(Да/Нет)":

```
print("Привет!")
what = input("Привет/Пока: ")
if what == "Пока":  
    print('Пока')
    exit()
elif what == "Привет":
    print("Как дела?")
what1 = input("Хорошо/Нормально/Плохо: ")

if what1 == "Плохо":
    print("Ничего страшного, я тебе его подниму!")
    print("Как хочешь его исправить? ")
    what1 = input("Рассказать шутку?(Да/Нет): ")
elif what1 == "Да":
    print("Лично мне клоуны совсем не кажутся смешными.")
    print("По правде говоря, я их боюсь. Даже не знаю, когда это началось.")
    print("Наверное, когда меня в детстве повели в цирк и клоун убил моего отца.")
elif input == "Нет":
    print("Окей")
elif what1 == "Нормально":
    print("Это прекрасно!")
elif what1 == "Хорошо":
        print("Вау! Я рад за тебя!")
what1 = input("Сколько тебе лет?: ")
if what1 < "16":
    print("Так ты школьник!")
    print("Как тебе школа?")
    what1 = input("Ужасно/Так себе/Нормально/Обожаю школу!: ")
if what1 == "Ужасно":
    print("В смысле 'Ужасно'? А друзья?")
    what1 = input("У тебя есть друзья?(Есть/Нету): ")
elif what1 == "Есть":
    print("Так веселись с ними!")
elif what1 == "Нету":
    print("Мне тебя жаль ):")
if what1 > "16":
    print("Так ты уже взрослый")
    what1 = input("Уже ходишь в универ/колледж?(Да/Нет): ")
if what1 == "Да":
    print("Молодец!")
if what1 == "Нет":
    print("Всё ещё впереди у тебя. Я в тебя верю!")
```

Comment: `if what1 < "16":` это не работает как вы ожидаете для строк. Приведите `what1` к числу и сравнивайте с числом `16`, а не строкой `"16"`

Comment: можете пожалуйста написать как это выглядит в коде

Comment: зайди на ютуб да посмотри любой гайд по питону)

Comment: Начните уже учить русский язык

Answer (score 0):

Основная проблема в том, что у вас не правильно расставлены условия if. Необходимо создавать вложенности, чтобы за вопросом следовали искомые ответы.
Также в 16 строке ошибка, должно быть what1, написано input.

Вот корректный код.

```
if what == "Пока":
    print('Пока')
    exit()
elif what == "Привет":
    print("Как дела?")
what1 = input("Хорошо/Нормально/Плохо: ")

if what1 == "Плохо":
    print("Ничего страшного, я тебе его подниму!")
    print("Как хочешь его исправить? ")
    what1 = input("Расказать шутку?(Да/Нет): ")
    if what1 == "Да":
        print("Лично мне клоуны совсем не кажутся смешными.")
        print("По правде говоря, я их боюсь. Даже не знаю, когда это началось.")
        print("Наверное, когда меня в детстве повели в цирк и клоун убил моего отца.")
    elif what1 == "Нет":
        print("Окей")
elif what1 == "Нормально":
    print("Это прекрасно!")
elif what1 == "Хорошо":
    print("Вау! Я рад за тебя!")
what1 = input("Сколько тебе лет?: ")
if what1 < "16":
    print("Так ты школьник!")
    print("Как тебе школа?")
    what1 = input("Ужастно/Так себе/Нормально/Обожаю школу!: ")
    if what1 == "Ужастно":
        print("Всмысле Ужастно? А друзья?")
        what1 = input("У тебя есть друзья?(Есть/Нету): ")
        if what1 == "Есть":
            print("Так веселись с ними!")
        elif what1 == "Нету":
            print("Мне тебя жаль ):")
if what1 > "16":
    print("Так ты уже взрослый")
    what1 = input("Уже ходишь в универ/колидж?(Да/Нет): ")
    if what1 == "Да":
        print("Молодец!")
    if what1 == "Нет":
        print("Всё ещё впереди у тебя я в тебя верю!")
```

Comment: взял код ошибка осталась,
Привет/Пока: Привет
Как дела?
Хорошо/Нормально/Плохо: Плохо
Ничего страшного, я тебе его подниму!
Как хочешь его исправить?
Расказать шутку?(Да/Нет): Да
Лично мне клоуны совсем не кажутся смешными.
По правде говоря, я их боюсь. Даже не знаю, когда это началось.
Наверное, когда меня в детстве повели в цирк и клоун убил моего отца.
Сколько тебе лет?: 10
Так ты школьник!
Как тебе школа?
Ужастно/Так себе/Нормально/Обожаю школу!: Ужастно
Всмысле Ужастно? А друзья?
У тебя есть друзья?(Есть/Нету): Есть
Так ты уже взрослый
Уже ходишь в универ/колидж?(Да/Нет):

Comment: @Dimonset не обратил внимание, **[31-34]** строчка тоже не правильно была написана.
Нужно было добавить отступы и поменять **elif на if**  в первом случае